# My ST-LINK V2 doesn't have four connection points on the board

Tags: stm32

I am trying to create my own openPGP token according to this site, https://nx3d.org/gnuk-st-link-v2/

I bought two ST-LINK V2 clone via Aliexpress but unfortunately my ST-LINK V2s don't have 4 connection points

[image: board top]
[image: board bottom]

I think the best way for me is to buy another ST-LINK V2 clone which has the four points. However, I need two weeks for delivery. Therefore I want to try something during the delivery. Don't you have any idea?

Currently I have female-female wires and female-male wires but don't have any other electric tools.

Comment: I think https://electronics.stackexchange.com/ would be a better place for this question. 
But if you have a close look at your PCB you could see the 4 pads instead of the 4 vias which should be the same for your purpose.

Answer (score 2):

I see four solder pads in the lower left of the first image, right next to the USB connector. The image is too blurry for me to be certain, but I suspect those make up a SWD port. You will need a soldering iron and some fine wire (I recommend 30ga wire-wrap wire) to attach a programmer.

Comment: <-USB +5V SWDIO SWCLK GND 10PIN->

Comment: As this seems to be the latest and cheapest model you can get right now, I've created the following pinout: https://github.com/rrottmann/stlink-v2-jtag/blob/master/ST%20LINK%20Stlink%20ST-Link%20V2%20Mini%20STM8%20STM32%20JTAG.jpg